# Wifi P2P Remote App

Tags: java, android, python

I would like to develop a Remote application for Peer-to-peer Android Device using TCP/IP connection. once one of the device successfully remote to the other, he/she will be able to see what the other device is doing (example : Controlling client device with parent, Sort of what a remote is to a tv). Is this possible to do or there is other way that is more efficient to do ? Any reference/road map is appreciated. code samples are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even though something like this is probably doable in principle, practically it sounds to me like a *huge* project to realize even for a very experienced team of developers. I'm afraid your question is therefor too broad to generate useful answers. You might want to check out this guide about how to ask a great question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve